# Kafka Streams Listing and Trying describe topics not part of the topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We noticed on our kafka broker logs that our stream applications are trying to describe topics that are not part of the topology.  It looks like it is periodically happening every 10 minutes.

Why is this occurring?  Why does streams need to know about topics that are not part of the topology?  Anyway to stop this?  Since the stream app does not have access to describe those topics we are getting a bunch of error logs.

We are using version 1.1.1

Comment: Kafka Streams requests metadata based on pattern based subscription. You cannot do anything about it. Can this explain what you observe?

Comment: Is the pattern based subscription configurable?  Why does it need to describe topics it does not care about?  This causes our error authentication logs to go crazy.

Comment: It's not configurable -- we use pattern subscription to avoid triggering `auto.topic.create`. We don't know if it's enabled server-side, and if it is and it's triggered, if might break Kafka Streams. Using pattern subscription we can avoid this issue. There a plans to allow "suppressing" auto-topic-create client side in future releases and than we can fix this issue. Atm, there is nothing you can do about it -- sorry.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, could you clarify what you mean by pattern based subscription?  We are not really sure what you mean.  For what it is worth, we have auto.topic. create set to false on the server.

Comment: It means we use this method to subscribe to topics: https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe-java.util.regex.Pattern-

Comment: @Chris I am facing this exactly same issue with kafka-streams using version 1.1.1, can you please tell if you were able to resolve this issue. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

It's a know issue, that will get fixed in the 2.5 release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7317