# Why does it seem Kafka Streams needs permissions for ClusterAction?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

From what I can tell about the ACLs for Kafka clients, even when wrapped up in the streams library, should never need permissions for ClusterAction. So I'm a bit confused why some of our streams users are showing up in the authorization logs `Principal = User:CN=USER is Denied Operation = ClusterAction from host = host.ip.address on resource = Cluster:LITERAL:cluster`. Is there something that streams does that actually requires that permission or is this an issue and we should be actually concerned.

Comment: Might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599482/kafka-streams-listing-and-trying-describe-topics-not-part-of-the-topology

Comment: Check out the docs for required ACLs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html